# How to write a generic code to make async call to Rest Service

Tags: c#-4.0, xamarin, c#-3.0

I am creating a Xamarin app and I have to populate master data into sqlite DB on mobile.

I am new to OOPS and Xamarin

I have multiple requests to be made to get data from WebApi. The request I need to make is more than 50 calls to get info.

Now, I need to write async generic code to achieve this.

For example: I have to populate data for EmployeeMaster, Company Master etc..

My generic code should be able to identify which URL to call and Which object has to be returned. My normal code is as follows below

The only varying data are RestUrl and TodoItem

```
    public async Task<List<TodoItem>> RefreshDataAsync()
    {
        Items = new List<TodoItem>();

        RestUrl = http://developer.xamarin.com:8081/api/todoitems{0}
        var uri = new Uri(string.Format(Constants.RestUrl, string.Empty));

        try
        {
            var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TodoItem>>(content);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(@"              ERROR {0}", ex.Message);
        }

        return Items;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look into Generics.
Something like this might help you.

```
public async Task<List<T>> RefreshDataAsync(string url)
{
    var items = new List<T>();

    try
    {
        var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(content);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(@"              ERROR {0}", ex.Message);
    }

    return items;
}
```

I would remove the List type too and only use T so the method would be able to load lists and single items.

```
public async Task<T> RefreshDataAsync(string url)
{
    try
    {
        var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
           return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(content);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(@"              ERROR {0}", ex.Message);
    }

    return new T;
}
```

Comment: It would be great if you could mark my solution as answer to your question. :-)

Comment: I have cast my vote on it. Can I mark explicitly as answer here?